# kotlin-test: How to test for a specific type like: "is y instance of X"

Tags: kotlin, instanceof, kotest

How to test if a val/var is of an expected type?

Is there something I am missing in Kotlin Test, like:

```
value shouldBe instanceOf<ExpectedType>()
```

Here is how I implemented it:

```
inline fun <reified T> instanceOf(): Matcher<Any> {
    return object : Matcher<Any> {
        override fun test(value: Any) =
                Result(value is T, "Expected an instance of type: ${T::class} \n Got: ${value::class}", "")

    }
}
```

Comment: must it be done with a custom matcher? Could just `assertTrue { value is ExpectedType }`

Comment: My goal is not to reinvent the wheel. If there is some 1 liner in kotlin-test, I would prefer it in favour of a custom implmentation.

Comment: `assertTrue { value is ExpectedType }` would work, but it doesn't read fluid and the exception message doesn't reveal any information of the actual exception, in case of an failure.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In KotlinTest, a lot is about proper spacing :)
You can use `should` to get access to a variety of built-in matchers.

```
import io.kotlintest.matchers.beInstanceOf
import io.kotlintest.should

value should beInstanceOf<Type>()
```

There is also an alternative syntax:

```
value.shouldBeInstanceOf<Type>()
```

See [here](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/doc/matchers.md) for more information.

Comment: That spacing is weired. I wonder why they added the alias `instanceOf(expected: KClass<*>): Matcher<Any?>` but not an refied infix version like in the question.

Comment: `shouldBe` is comparing against **equality** of its left and right argument. While they could have overloaded it for matchers, it would be confusing (e.g. what if the right-hand argument is passed as type `Any`?). I think the circumstance that the same function name always performs the same validation helps understanding, even if less intuitive from an English language point of view.

Comment: FYI `shouldBe` is implemented to be usable with `Matcher` 's, so it is not tied to equality checks. Here you can see its implementation: [dsl.kt](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/kotlintest-assertions/src/commonMain/kotlin/io/kotlintest/dsl.kt#L86)

Comment: Thanks! Good to know, even though questionable that `x should y`, `x shouldBe y` and `x shouldHave y` can be used interchangeably with matchers. Apparently they want to make everyone happy...

Comment: The idea behind shouldBe and shouldHave was to allow matchers to be named things like "size" so you could then write, a shouldHave size(4). In hindsight it was not a great idea.

Answer (score 4):

Since Kotlin 1.5 there is a nice solution included in kotlin-test:

```kotlin
assertIs<TypeExpected>(value)
```

This will not only assert that `value` is of type `TypeExpected`, it will also smart cast `value`, so that you can access all methods of `TypeExpected`. Just include the dependency, e.g:

```
testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5:1.7.10")
```

And you can do stuff like this

```kotlin
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals
import kotlin.test.assertIs

class AssertIsTests {

    @Test
    fun `test for list`() {
        val list = Collector.List.collect(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
        assertEquals(5, list.size)

        // assertEquals(1, list[0])  won't compile: list is of type Collection<Int> which doesn't support []
        assertIs<List<Int>>(list)         // from now on list is of type List<Int>!
        assertEquals(4, list.indexOf(3))  // now there are all list methods
        assertEquals(1, list[0])          // including indexed getters
    }

    @Test
    fun `test for set`() {
        val set = Collector.Set.collect(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
        assertEquals(3, set.size)  // Set with duplicates removed

        assertIs<Set<Int>>(set)    // from now on set is of Type Set<Int>
    }
}

enum class Collector {
    List {
        override fun collect(vararg args: Int) = args.toList()
    },
    Set {
        override fun collect(vararg args: Int) = args.toSet()
    };

    abstract fun collect(vararg args: Int): Collection<Int>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 Kotlintest library was renamed to Kotest and package names changed accordingly. So I decided to publish an updated version of the @TheOperator's answer.

To check that a `value` is *an instance or a subtype of* `Type`:

```
import io.kotest.matchers.should
import io.kotest.matchers.types.beInstanceOf

value should beInstanceOf<Type>()
```

An alternative to this is a method from [Core Matchers](https://kotest.io/docs/assertions/core-matchers.html):

```
import io.kotest.matchers.types.shouldBeInstanceOf

val castedValue: Type = value.shouldBeInstanceOf<Type>()
```

Note that in this case a value casted to the specified type is returned, which can be used in further validations.

---

In case you need *exact type matching*, use another set of methods:

```
import io.kotest.matchers.should
import io.kotest.matchers.types.beOfType
import io.kotest.matchers.types.shouldBeTypeOf

value should beOfType<Type>()
val castedValue: Type = value.shouldBeTypeOf<Type>()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write assert statement using JUnit like

```
assertEquals(ExpectedClassName::class.java, actualInstance.javaClass)
```